# Did not get a single choice of Exotic gear for completing the Red War campaign

Tags: destiny-2

According to the Destiny 2 wikis and gamepedias out there, certain exotics are supposedly guaranteed to be given to the player during specific quests in the Red War main campaign mission for D2.  Specifically, there should be a choice of 1 of 3 exotic class armors, 1 of 3 exotic weapons, and 1 exotic weapon for completing the campaign.

I started playing D2 from the New Light expansion. I've completed the Red War campaign -- twice in fact, on both my Titan and my Hunter.  I have not seen a single exotic reward, nor have I seen a single offer after completion any of those missions to give me an exotic reward.

Is there something else that I have to do in order to get those? I was really looking forwards to getting the Actium War Rigs for my Titan, but I'm guessing that's going to have to wait until I can figure this out.

Comment: Not a definite answer, however you aren't the only one experiencing this. People are speculating these were taken out in the New Light version (some say they were taken out as early as Forsaken), but Bungie has been silent on the matter if this is expected behavior or a bug

Comment: I presume they're not at the Postmaster or other similar Tower NPC?

Comment: This may well change in September 2020 with some content being vaulted.